# What do we know about periodic modules in p-groups?

Tags: modular-representation-theory

a module in KG,where G is a p-group and K a field of characteristic p, is called periodic if $ \Omega^{n} M = M $, for a natural n.
In general the full subcategory of periodic modules seems to have also wild representation type( [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-32/issue-3/Wild-categories-of-periodic-modules/10.1215/ijm/1255989005.full) ).
I wonder if there are still some interesting results about periodic modules.
So I search for a kind of up-to-date survey paper listing such results.
some questions are:

In which dimensions can a module of period n occur?(results like in this paper:
[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-23/issue-2/The-dimensions-of-periodic-modules-over-modular-group-algebras/10.1215/ijm/1256048241.full)
where it is proven that a power of p divides the dimension)

Which periods can occur in a given group?

Is there any interesting relation of the subcategory of periodic modules and the pure group structure?

Thank you

edit: Another question: Can we give an example of a periodic module in an arbitrary KG?Maybe there is a canonical construction.

edit2: after reading parts of benson im a bit confused.for example in the introduction he says compelextity 1 is equivalent being periodic.But he says something else in a later theorem.
Is the following correct?:
M has complextity 1 iff

$M_E $ has maximal complextity 1 for an elementar abelian subgroup E of G iff

M is a direct sum of indecomposable periodcis and projectives iff

in the minimal projective resolution the terms have bounded dimension.

Answer (score 4):

One interesting result on which periods can occur is that if $\operatorname{Ext}^*_{kG}(k,k)$ is finitely generated over a subring generated by elements of degree at most $m$, then any periodic $kG$-module has period at most $m$.  You can find this result (and many other relevant ones) in Benson's book Representations and Cohomology vol 2: that and the references given there would be a good place to start.

Okuyama and Sasaki's  "Periodic modules of large periods for metacyclic p-groups" (J.Algebra 144)  might interest you.  I wrote a paper about which $p$-groups can have periodic modules of dimension $p$ (the smallest possible dimension) and what the periods are, called `Periodic modules of dimension p' in Quarterly Journal of Mathematics 61 no. 3.

So far as I know, the answers to questions like "which periods can occur in a given group?", and "in which dimensions can a module of period n occur?" are not known except for in specific cases.

In response to your edit: if $G$ is a $p$-group, choose $H \leq G$ of order $p$. There's an exact sequence $0\to k \to kH \to kH \to k \to 0$, induce it to $G$.  The middle terms are projective, so $k\uparrow^G$ is periodic of period two.

Comment: thank you for your edit!But I think it has period 1 for p=2.


Comment: You're right - I should have said "period dividing 2"